# Sort text file with multicolumns

Tags: bash

I have several lines like

```
Eff from the first object: 0.000528103 and for second: 0.000537639. Ratio: 1.0180570835 -% .0101805708
```

How can I sort them in bash based on the ratio or the number after the "-%"  ? I ve tried

```
sort -t\% -k 1,1n
```

but does not work as expected

Comment: The field after the `%` is field 2. `sort -t% -k2n` should work for that case. For ratio, you could try `sort -t: -k3n`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to escape `%`. Also, as the comment mentioned, you want the second field if you are trying to sort based on the number after `%` symbol.

```
sort -n -t% -k 2
```